# Scala way of Tailing files

Tags: scala

I want to monitor a log file using Scala. The specific problem with logs is that you need to be able to account for logrotation as well (which is one of the essential features of Linux tail).

I know that for pure Java there is [Tailer](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/input/Tailer.html), but I was wondering if there is a similar Scala implementation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's easy to wrap in Scala from the looks of it.

```
object ScalaTailer {
   private val DefaultBufSize = 4096

   def apply(file: File, onFileNotFound: => Unit = (), onFileRotated: => Unit = (),
              handleException: Exception => Unit = (), handleLine: String => Unit = (),
              delayMillis: Long = 1000, end: Boolean = false, reOpen: Boolean = false,
              bufSize: Int = DefaultBufSize) = {
     val listener = new TailerListener {
        override def fileNotFound() = onFileNotFound
        override def fileRotated() = onFileRotated
        override def handle(ex: Exception) = handleException(ex)
        override def handle(line: String) = handeLine(line)
     }
     new Tailer(file, listener, delayMillis, end, reOpen, bufSize)
  }
}

val tailer = ScalaTailer(myFile, handleLine = println)
```

This is probably the reason why there's no Scala implementation of it. Besides, the Apache Commons stuff is pretty robust, so it's probably a good idea to use it!